# How to code a, and read in a binary tree of modified(!) Huffman codes in PHP

Tags: php, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, huffman-code

I am writing a class for the **decoding** of fax data encoded with [modified Huffman](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/0471221538.appd) code.

Data is coded line by line: data describes each pixel row. Lines are coded as records of variable length. The pixel bits are stored in the bits of code words, least significant first.

Recently the code word list (182 elements) is defined as an array:

```
/**
 * [0] code word
 * [1] length of code word
 * [2] run length of color bits
 * [3] 0 = white / 1 = black
 * [4] 1 = termination codes / 0 = make up codes
 */
const CODEWORDS = [
   [0b00110101, 8, 0, 0, 1],             // termination codes white
   [0b000111, 6, 1, 0, 1],
   [0b0111, 4, 2, 0, 1],
   [0b1000, 4, 3, 0, 1],
   [0b1011, 4, 4, 0, 1],
   [0b1100, 4, 5, 0, 1],
   [0b1110, 4, 6, 0, 1],
   [0b1111, 4, 7, 0, 1],
   [0b10011, 5, 8, 0, 1],
   ...
];
```

Before usage the array is sorted in descending order according to the length of the code words.

In a first approach I´m able to find the correct code words with repeating `foreach`-iterations over this array - but it's (not surprising!) **terribly slow**.

It is clear to me, that an increase in performance can only be achieved using a binary tree.
But even after looking at several explanations here or solutions (libraries) in GitHub, I can't find access to

- how to transfer the data from the array into a binary tree
- how to browse the tree to get the right leaf

If someone could help me there, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Attempting to do this in PHP will (IMHO) always prove slow, you would be better off with a lower level language (c, c++ etc).

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but I'm less interested in the result than in the learning effect.

Comment: Are you sure that the linked table is correct? It has the same codes for white 39 and 40, as well as the same codes for black 9 and 10.

Comment: This looks like a more definitive reference: [ITU-T Recommendation T.6](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-T.6-198811-I!!PDF-E).

Comment: @Mark Adler Thanks for looking carefully at the tables. But the document you linked also contains the same duplicates. The Code Word tables are identical

Comment: No it doesn't. Look again more carefully at white code 39 and black code 10. The ITU document is correct and has no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the correct codes (see my comments on your question), then you start by building one set of codes for white and one for black. For each, you start the tree with a branch for the first bit being zero, and another branch for one. Break up your set of codes into two sets, one set where all the codes start with zero, and the other where they all start with one. For each of those, make two branches. Break up each set based on the second bit. Once you get to a branch with one code and you just used the last bit of that code, you now have a leaf. In that leaf you store the symbol for the code, e.g. 63 for white code `00110100`. If you get to a branch and there are *no* codes, then you again have a leaf, but this time it will result in a decoding error if it is reached.

To decode, take the first bit and go down that branch. Choose the second branch depending on the second bit. And so on until you get to a leaf. Then emit that symbol and start back again at the root with the subsequent bit. Or terminate if you end up at an error leaf.

Comment: Yes, the principle described corresponds to what I have read elsewhere - too bad that I have not yet been able to derive the specific implementation

Comment: To build, sort the codes (left justified, not right justified like you would with numbers). Use recursion. At each recursion you have two pointers into the sorted list, a start and end, where all of those codes have the same prefix. Search for where the next bit changes from a 0 to 1. Now call your recursive function for each of those sets.